# Failure with variables in javascript (I guess) When using one, the other overlaps

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a test and I need that when you pres the button it gives you the number of attempts (the times the button is pressed) and the percentage of successes of each attempt (which is updated each time the button is pressed), but when is counting the attempts, only the percentage of the first time the button is clicked counts, the other times it does not count. If I remove the attempts, I get the percentage correctly, but when trying to do both it cannot make the percentage ... Can someone help me? Maybe it's a rookie mistake, but I can't resolve it. I leave here the two codes, both JavaScript and HTML:

```js
function corregir() {
  var n1, n2, n3, n4;

  if (document.getElementById("r11").checked == true &&
    document.getElementById("r12").checked == false &&
    document.getElementById("r13").checked == false &&
    document.getElementById("r14").checked == true) {
    n1 = 1;
  } else {
    n1 = 0;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("r22").checked == true) {
    n2 = 1;
  } else {
    n2 = 0;
  }


  if (document.getElementById("34").selected == true) {
    n3 = 1;
  } else {
    n3 = 0;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("4").value == "Structured Query Language") {
    n4 = 1;
  } else {
    n4 = 0;
  }

  var suma = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;
  var nota = suma * 100 / 4;
  //if I activate this by deactivating the onclick, the percentage works
  //document.getElementById("porcentaje").innerHTML = "has acertado un "+ nota +"% de respuestas.";        


  // Ponemos el contador a 0
  var int = 0;
  int = int + 1;

  //IF I REMOVE THIS, THE PERCENTAGE IS GOING RIGHT:
  document.getElementById("boton").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("boton").value = "✿ Reintentar ✿";
    document.getElementById("intentos").innerHTML = "Intento número " + ++int + ". En este intento has acertado un " + nota + "% de respuestas.";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1><u>Test sobre SQL</u></h1>

<form method="POST">
  <b>1. De estas opciones, ¿cuáles puedes hacer en una base de datos SQL? <i class="pistas">Selecciona más de una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="r11" class="respst" required>Manipular datos<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="r12" class="respst">Jugar al Pac-Man<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="r13" class="respst">Hacer dibujos con letras y números<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="r14" class="respst">Hacer cálculos avanzados y álgebra<br><br>


  <b>2. ¿Cuál es un tipo de base de datos SQL? <i class="pistas">Selecciona solo una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
  <input name="2" type="radio" id="r21" class="respst" required>MongoDB<br>
  <input name="2" type="radio" id="r22" class="respst">Oracle<br>
  <input name="2" type="radio" id="r23" class="respst">Redis<br>
  <input name="2" type="radio" id="r24" class="respst">Apache Cassandra<br><br>

  <b>3. Elije la base de datos que <u>no</u> sea SQL. <i class="pistas">Despliega y elige una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
  <select name="resPreg3">
    <option id="30" value="0">--Elige una respuesta--</option>
    <option id="31" value="0">Firebird</option>
    <option id="32" value="0">Microsoft Access</option>
    <option id="33" value="0">MariaDB</option>
    <option id="34" value="1">CouchDB</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <b>4. ¿Qué significan las siglas SQL en inglés? <i class="pistas">Escribe tu respuesta en el cuadro</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
  <textarea id="4" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu respuesta" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea><br><br>

</form>

<input class="boton" type="submit" value="✎ Corregir " onclick="corregir()" id="boton">
<span id="intentos"></span><span id="porcentaje"></span>
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to your issues, but `id` values cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here

1. You're adding an event handler for the button in HTML and in code. Remove it from the HTML and attach the click event in javascript.
2. In order to track the number of attempts the variable to do so needs to be outside of the scope of the event handler.

I think this fixes it how you expected

```js
var int = 0;

function corregir() {
  var n1, n2, n3, n4;

  if (document.getElementById("r11").checked == true &&
    document.getElementById("r12").checked == false &&
    document.getElementById("r13").checked == false &&
    document.getElementById("r14").checked == true) {
    n1 = 1;
  } else {
    n1 = 0;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("r22").checked == true) {
    n2 = 1;
  } else {
    n2 = 0;
  }


  if (document.getElementById("34").selected == true) {
    n3 = 1;
  } else {
    n3 = 0;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("4").value == "Structured Query Language") {
    n4 = 1;
  } else {
    n4 = 0;
  }

  var suma = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;
  var nota = suma * 100 / 4;

  // Ponemos el contador a 0



  document.getElementById("boton").value = "✿ Reintentar ✿";
  document.getElementById("intentos").innerHTML = "Intento número " + ++int + ". En este intento has acertado un " + nota + "% de respuestas.";

}

document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", corregir);
```

```html
<h1><u>Test sobre SQL</u></h1>

<form method="POST">
  <b>1. De estas opciones, ¿cuáles puedes hacer en una base de datos SQL? <i class="pistas">Selecciona más de una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="r11" class="respst" required>Manipular datos<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="r12" class="respst">Jugar al Pac-Man<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="r13" class="respst">Hacer dibujos con letras y números<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="r14" class="respst">Hacer cálculos avanzados y álgebra<br><br>


  <b>2. ¿Cuál es un tipo de base de datos SQL? <i class="pistas">Selecciona solo una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
  <input name="2" type="radio" id="r21" class="respst" required>MongoDB<br>
  <input name="2" type="radio" id="r22" class="respst">Oracle<br>
  <input name="2" type="radio" id="r23" class="respst">Redis<br>
  <input name="2" type="radio" id="r24" class="respst">Apache Cassandra<br><br>

  <b>3. Elije la base de datos que <u>no</u> sea SQL. <i class="pistas">Despliega y elige una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
  <select name="resPreg3">
    <option id="30" value="0">--Elige una respuesta--</option>
    <option id="31" value="0">Firebird</option>
    <option id="32" value="0">Microsoft Access</option>
    <option id="33" value="0">MariaDB</option>
    <option id="34" value="1">CouchDB</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <b>4. ¿Qué significan las siglas SQL en inglés? <i class="pistas">Escribe tu respuesta en el cuadro</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
  <textarea id="4" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu respuesta" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea><br><br>

</form>

<input class="boton" type="submit" value="✎ Corregir " id="boton">
<span id="intentos"></span><span id="porcentaje"></span>
```

Sidenote: It works, but you shouldnt use numbers alone for `id` of html elements, they should start with an a-z

Comment: Thank you!! It has worked but keeping the two event handlers for the button, if I removed it from HTML it did not work for me.